# Provisioning of Microsoft forms webpart to modern pages using powershell

Tags: powershell, sharepoint-online

Anyone tried to provision Microsoft Forms web part to modern pages using PowerShell script?

I have created multiple pages and able to add many web parts using PnP commands in PowerShell. But failed to add this Microsoft Forms web part to feedback page to collect feedback from users. This is the only thing I stuck at. Can anyone throw ideas please.

Below command is failing as the component with name "Microsoft Forms" web part is not found.

Add-PnPClientSideWebPart -Page $feedbackPage -Component "Microsoft Forms" -Section 1 -Column 1 -Order 2

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Back then we had used the iframe web part which rendered the web part inside iframe.

Now we have officially available the MicrosoftForms using below command.

Add-PnPClientSideWebPart -Page $feedbackPage -Component MicrosoftForms -Section 1 -Column 1 -Order 2